# system() without prompt, c++, winmain

Tags: c++, system, winmain

I am using c++ and i have a program that works with winmain. 
I do not want the system() call to open and close a window.

example:

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
    system("dir > nul 2> nul");

    return 0;
}
```

I want to use system calls but I don't want them to open a new window.

Thanks in advance.

**edit:**

I found this solution:

To execute cmd commands without opening a window i create a bat file (the program does this) then i use this code:

`ShellExecute(NULL, "open", "Directory_Of_Bat_File", NULL, NULL, 0);`

This opens the bat file and executes the commands.
I also noticed that you don't need system() to delete the bat file but you can delete it by writing:

```
del Directory_Of_Bat_File
```

Inside the bat file and this will delete it when you execute the bat file (it will delete itself).
This without opening a new window.

Comment: If you have a solution, please post it as an answer rather than editing it into your question. (Yes, you can answer your own question; you can even accept your own answer if it's the best solution to your problem.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution:

To execute cmd commands without opening a window I create a bat file (the program does this) then I use this code:

```
ShellExecute(NULL, "open", "Directory_Of_Bat_File", NULL, NULL, 0);
```

This opens the bat file and executes the commands. I also noticed that you don't need system() to delete the bat file but you can delete it by writing:

```
del Directory_Of_Bat_File
```

Inside the bat file and this will delete it when you execute the bat file (it will delete itself). This without opening a new window.

Answer (score 2):

Since system, by its definition, creates a new process with a command interpreter, you can't do that.

From MSDN subject [`system`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/277bwbdz%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

> The system function passes command to the command interpreter, which
>   executes the string as an operating-system command.

If you want to do "dir", since that's a built-in command in the "cmd.exe" or whatever command interpreter you are using, it's pretty difficult to "fix" this issue - even using `ShellExecute` or `CreateProcess` will not help a whole lot, since you will get a window either way - it may be minimizes or something like that, but it will still be a window there.

Comment: Is there any other way to use cmd commands such as del without opening a new window?

Answer (score 0):

Use `CreateProcess` or `ShellExecute` to launch the process, there you can pass options related to windows. what system() executes can normally be found in environment, `getenv("ComSpec")`